# SQL - How to select a row having a column with max value

Tags: sql, oracle

```
date                 value

18/5/2010, 1 pm        40
18/5/2010, 2 pm        20
18/5/2010, 3 pm        60
18/5/2010, 4 pm        30
18/5/2010, 5 pm        60
18/5/2010, 6 pm        25
```

i need to query for the row having max(value)(i.e. 60). So, here we get two rows. From that, I need the row with the lowest time stamp for that day(i.e 18/5/2010, 3 pm -> 60)

Comment: Thanks all. Now if the date spans for 10 days, I need to make this query for each of the 10 days resulting in 10 rows, with each having a max value of that particular day. Please assist me on this.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

Keywords like TOP, LIMIT, ROWNUM, ...etc are database dependent. Please read this article for more information.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Select_(SQL)#Result_limits

Oracle: ROWNUM could be used.

```
select * from (select * from table 
order by value desc, date_column) 
where rownum = 1;
```

Answering the question more specifically:

```
select high_val, my_key
from (select high_val, my_key
      from mytable
      where something = 'avalue'
      order by high_val desc)
where rownum <= 1
```

Comment: +1 For this question I'd recommend the ROWNUM query. Oracle optimizes these sorts of queries very well (i.e. even though it requires a sort, it doesn't actually sort the entire table - it just keeps the topmost row as it scans the table) - and with an appropriate index it won't even have to do that.

Comment: Excellent answer. Anyway, I prefer LIMIT :)

Answer (score 34):

Analytics! This avoids having to access the table twice:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
       FIRST_VALUE(date_col)  OVER (ORDER BY value_col DESC, date_col ASC),
       FIRST_VALUE(value_col) OVER (ORDER BY value_col DESC, date_col ASC)
FROM   mytable;
```

Comment: I would be interested in seeing what kind of performance difference this had, from a purely educational point of view. From Toms asktom.oracle site i had understood there were significant overheads in using FIRST_VALUE. Is it possible that you could direct me to some performance results comparing them?

Comment: If you have an index on (value_col, date_col) you'll find that Oracle will do quite well using Sujee's query, since it will use the `COUNT STOPKEY` optimization.

Comment: It avoids scanning the table twice, but it calculates the first_value column for every row, and then the distinct discards them all but one. Better than most other answers, but aggregating is the way to go here.

Comment: Yeah. Sujee beat me to the ROWNUM solution which is better :)

Answer (score 13):

Answer is to add a sub select:

```
SELECT [columns]
FROM table t1
WHERE value= (select max(value) from table)
AND date = (select MIN(date) from table t2 where t1.value = t2.value)
```

this should work and gets rid of the neccesity of having an extra sub select in the date clause.

Comment: Any non-aggregate in the HAVING clause needs to be part of a GROUP BY clause

Comment: Excelent point. I tested mine on sybase, it lets you get away with that. I modified my answer to suit the required database

Comment: um... you still have a sub select - in fact, two of them.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback, yes there are two, but the standard alternative is to do `AND date = select min(date) from table where value = (select max(value) from table))`. i refference J brooks answer (up 3 from this one) as proof. by refferencing the already aquired value of the previous sub select you save 1 level of nesting

Comment: ah, I get what you're saying now. ... of course, all the subselects are unnecessary :)

Comment: This may not return any rows, you are asking for the max value overall, and the min date overall in the same row... odds are that this won't exist, so this will return no rows.

Answer (score 10):

```
SQL> create table t (mydate,value)
  2  as
  3  select to_date('18/5/2010, 1 pm','dd/mm/yyyy, hh am'), 40 from dual union all
  4  select to_date('18/5/2010, 2 pm','dd/mm/yyyy, hh am'), 20 from dual union all
  5  select to_date('18/5/2010, 3 pm','dd/mm/yyyy, hh am'), 60 from dual union all
  6  select to_date('18/5/2010, 4 pm','dd/mm/yyyy, hh am'), 30 from dual union all
  7  select to_date('18/5/2010, 5 pm','dd/mm/yyyy, hh am'), 60 from dual union all
  8  select to_date('18/5/2010, 6 pm','dd/mm/yyyy, hh am'), 25 from dual
  9  /

Table created.

SQL> select min(mydate) keep (dense_rank last order by value) mydate
  2       , max(value) value
  3    from t
  4  /

MYDATE                   VALUE
------------------- ----------
18-05-2010 15:00:00         60

1 row selected.
```

Regards,
Rob.

Comment: Good, but still Oracle will do a full scan - it cannot apply the COUNT STOPKEY optimization, unfortunately :(

Comment: True. And logical because to know for sure something is the maximal value, you'll have to visit them all, or have them pre-ordered like in an index.

Answer (score 9):

Technically, this is the same answer as @Sujee.  It also depends on your version of Oracle as to whether it works.  (I think this syntax was introduced in Oracle 12??)

```
SELECT *
FROM   table
ORDER BY value DESC, date_column ASC
FETCH  first 1 rows only;
```

As I say, if you look under the bonnet, I think this code is unpacked internally by the Oracle Optimizer to read like @Sujee's.  However, I'm a sucker for pretty coding, and nesting `select` statements without a good reason does not qualify as beautiful!! :-P

Answer (score 2):

In Oracle:

This gets the key of the max(high_val) in the table according to the range.

```
select high_val, my_key
from (select high_val, my_key
      from mytable
      where something = 'avalue'
      order by high_val desc)
where rownum <= 1
```

Answer (score 1):

In Oracle DB:

```
create table temp_test1 (id number, value number, description varchar2(20));

insert into temp_test1 values(1, 22, 'qq');
insert into temp_test1 values(2, 22, 'qq');
insert into temp_test1 values(3, 22, 'qq');
insert into temp_test1 values(4, 23, 'qq1');
insert into temp_test1 values(5, 23, 'qq1');
insert into temp_test1 values(6, 23, 'qq1');

SELECT MAX(id), value, description FROM temp_test1 GROUP BY value, description;

Result:
    MAX(ID) VALUE DESCRIPTION
    -------------------------
    6         23    qq1
    3         22    qq
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest answer would be

--Setup a test table called "t1"

```
create table t1
(date datetime,
value int)
```

-- Load the data.
-- Note: date format different than in the question

```
insert into t1
Select '5/18/2010 13:00',40
union all
Select '5/18/2010 14:00',20
union all
Select '5/18/2010 15:00',60 
union all
Select '5/18/2010 16:00',30 
union all
Select '5/18/2010 17:00',60 
union all
Select '5/18/2010 18:00',25
```

-- find the row with the max qty and min date.

```
select *
from t1
where value = 
    (select max(value)  from t1)
and date = 
    (select min(date) 
    from t1
    where value = (select max(value)  from t1))
```

I know you can do the "TOP 1" answer, but usually your solution gets just complicated enough that you can't use that for some reason.

Comment: Three extra accesses on the same table are just unnecessary in Oracle for this requirement.

Comment: Extra access? This will have the same execution plan as some of the others on here that look like they do less.... but are less readable.  And I understand that Oracle doesn't have a TOP command.

Answer (score -5):

### You can use this function, ORACLE DB

```
 public string getMaximumSequenceOfUser(string columnName, string tableName, string username)
    {
        string result = "";
        var query = string.Format("Select MAX ({0})from {1} where CREATED_BY = {2}", columnName, tableName, username.ToLower());

        OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection(_context.Database.Connection.ConnectionString);
        OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand(query, conn);
        try
        {
            conn.Open();
            OracleDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            dr.Read();
            result = dr[0].ToString();
            dr.Dispose();
        }
        finally
        {
            conn.Close();
        }
        return result;
    }
```