# How to display the MAX of a count

Tags: sql, oracle

Hi I'm trying to write a query that returns the category that has the maximum amount of people with interests in that category (if that makes sense)

So anyway here's my attempt at it so far..

```
SELECT category, MAX(catcount) FROM (
select category, catid, COUNT(id) AS catcount FROM (
SELECT  DISTINCT empinterest.id, INTERESTCATEGORY.CATID AS catid, INTERESTCATEGORY.category   FROM EMPINTEREST
INNER JOIN interest ON EMPINTEREST.INTID =  INTEREST.ID 
INNER JOIN interestcategory ON INTEREST.CATID = INTERESTCATEGORY.CATID
order by empinterest.id)
group by catid, category) GROUP BY category
```

I know that the first sub-select will give me the category and the amount of interests people have in that category which is why I tried to just run a max on the count but I think the group by clause is what is stopping the max value being returned. I've had an attempt at using a HAVING clause but can't seem to get the syntax right so hopefully someone will be able to give me a hand. Thanks in advance!

Here's the tables if that helps, and if anyone needs anymore clarification I'll provide it!

```
CREATE TABLE department
(
dptID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL
);


CREATE TABLE interestcategory 
(
catID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
category VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL
);


CREATE TABLE employee (
id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
title VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
fName VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
sName VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
jTitle VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
startDate DATE NOT NULL,
teamLead VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
employeeType VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
dptID INT NOT NULL REFERENCES department(dptID)
);


CREATE TABLE interest 
(
id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
interest VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
catID INT NOT NULL REFERENCES interestcategory(catID)
  );
  CREATE TABLE empinterest 
(
id INT NOT NULL REFERENCES employee(id),
intID INT NOT NULL REFERENCES interest(id),
PRIMARY KEY (id, intID)
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at how you could do it in general:

```
CREATE TABLE categories (
  category_id NUMBER,
  category_name VARCHAR2(20)
);

CREATE TABLE dep_table (
  category_id NUMBER
);

INSERT INTO categories VALUES (1, 'A');
INSERT INTO categories VALUES (2, 'B');
INSERT INTO categories VALUES (3, 'C');

INSERT INTO dep_table VALUES (1);
INSERT INTO dep_table VALUES (1);
INSERT INTO dep_table VALUES (1);
INSERT INTO dep_table VALUES (2);
INSERT INTO dep_table VALUES (3);
INSERT INTO dep_table VALUES (3);

COMMIT:

WITH
  main_query AS (
    SELECT ct.category_name, dt.category_id
      FROM categories ct
        JOIN dep_table dt ON (ct.category_id = dt.category_id)
  )
SELECT category_name, COUNT(1)
  FROM main_query
GROUP BY category_name
HAVING COUNT(1) = (SELECT MAX(COUNT(1)) FROM main_query GROUP BY category_name);
```

So your query would look like this:

```
WITH
  main_query AS (
    SELECT
      DISTINCT
        empinterest.id,
        INTERESTCATEGORY.CATID AS catid,
        INTERESTCATEGORY.category
    FROM EMPINTEREST
      INNER JOIN interest ON EMPINTEREST.INTID =  INTEREST.ID 
      INNER JOIN interestcategory ON INTEREST.CATID = INTERESTCATEGORY.CATID
  )
SELECT category, COUNT(1)
  FROM main_query
GROUP BY catid, category
HAVING COUNT(1) = (SELECT MAX(COUNT(1)) FROM main_query GROUP BY catid, category);
```

Comment: Thanks very much for this answer, I'd never heard of the WITH clause before but it definitely makes things a lot easier and neater!

Would it be possible for you to explain how COUNT(1) works please?

Comment: @Jimmy `COUNT` counts occurrences of non-NULL values, so you could put there `empinterest.id` instead, or the asterisk `*`, or another column that counting could be based on. I've grown accustomed to use `COUNT(1)` instead of `COUNT(*)`, because I've read somewhere that is is better for performance. When you use `COUNT(1)`, it just counts the number of rows in each of the groups defined by the `GROUP BY` clause. Hoping this is clear enough, if not, please do ask.

Answer (score 0):

You could do your subquery and select the top row:

```
SELECT category, catcount FROM (
  select category, catid, COUNT(id) AS catcount 
  FROM (
    SELECT
      DISTINCT empinterest.id, 
      INTERESTCATEGORY.CATID AS catid,
      INTERESTCATEGORY.category
    FROM EMPINTEREST
      INNER JOIN interest ON EMPINTEREST.INTID =  INTEREST.ID 
      INNER JOIN interestcategory ON INTEREST.CATID = INTERESTCATEGORY.CATID
    order by empinterest.id)
  group by catid, category order by catcount desc)
WHERE ROWNUM <= 1
```

see also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2854257/sql-how-to-select-a-row-having-a-column-with-max-value).

The only trouble is when you want to be able to get all rows that satisfy `count(id) = max(count(id))`, then you'd have to use `HAVING` I guess.