# SQL - How to select a row having a column with max value (+ group by)

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm building up on the question referenced here:
[SQL - How to select a row having a column with max value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2854257/sql-how-to-select-a-row-having-a-column-with-max-value)

> ```
> date                 value
>
> 18/5/2010, 1 pm        40
> 18/5/2010, 2 pm        20
> 18/5/2010, 3 pm        60
> 18/5/2010, 4 pm        30
> 18/5/2010, 5 pm        60
> 18/5/2010, 6 pm        25
> ```
>
> i need to query for the row having max(value)(i.e. 60). So, here we
>   get two rows. From that, I need the row with the lowest time stamp for
>   that day(i.e 18/5/2010, 3 pm -> 60)

How can we build on the answer as provided by Sujee:

> ```
> select high_val, my_key
> from (select high_val, my_key
>       from mytable
>       where something = 'avalue'
>       order by high_val desc)
> where rownum <= 1
> ```

if the data has a 3rd column "category".

```
date                 value    category

18/5/2010, 1 pm        40      1
18/5/2010, 2 pm        20      1
18/5/2010, 3 pm        60      1
18/5/2010, 4 pm        30      2
18/5/2010, 5 pm        60      2
18/5/2010, 6 pm        25      2
```

FYI - I'm using Oracle, and trying to avoid a nested join (hence the rownum trick)

The goal is to have the same answer, but with a group by category

Comment: Please explain what `category` has to do with the question.  What result set are you looking for?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you want to select the row with the highest `high_val` for each category. If so, you can use `row_number()` to rank each row within a category according to its `high_val` value, and only select the highest ranked rows i.e. `rn = 1`:

```
select * from (
    select row_number() over (partition by category order by high_val desc, date asc) rn, *
    from mytable
    where something = 'avalue'
) t1 where rn = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add an additional key to the `order by`:

```
select high_val, my_key
from (select high_val, my_key
      from mytable
      where something = 'avalue'
      order by high_val desc, date asc
     )
where rownum = 1;
```

If you want `category` in the result set, then select it in the subquery.

Comment: is this not going to return only one row? I'm reading it but I think I need two rows because of the category