# How to query a row with a unique identifier with their respective max value?

Tags: mysql, sql, select, max

Assume I have table `exection_records` which has the data:

```
+----+----------+---------------------+
| id | handle   | finishedAt          |
+----+----------+---------------------+
| 1  | task_foo | 2015-08-16 03:10:33 |
| 2  | task_foo | 2015-08-15 04:00:27 |
| 3  | task_foo | 2015-08-14 02:10:25 |
| 4  | task_bar | 2015-08-17 03:00:25 |
| 5  | task_bar | 2015-08-16 02:01:25 |
| 6  | task_bar | 2015-08-13 06:02:50 |
+----+----------+---------------------+
```

Now I want to get the row where `finishedAt` at is at its most recent timestamp for each unique handle, that is:

```
+----+----------+---------------------+
| id | handle   | finishedAt          |
+----+----------+---------------------+
| 1  | task_foo | 2015-08-16 03:01:33 |
| 4  | task_bar | 2015-08-17 03:00:25 |
+----+----------+---------------------+
```

I know that there is [`MAX`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-maximum-column.html) in MySQL.

I could get the very latest record for each task via:

```
SELECT *,MAX(finishedAt) FROM db.execution_records where taskHandle = 'task_foo';
SELECT *,MAX(finishedAt) FROM db.execution_records where taskHandle = 'task_bar';
```

Yet I do not want to issue multiple queries but one, and I do not want to name the handles.

How could I achieve my query?

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32059558/sql-how-to-select-a-row-having-a-column-with-max-value-group-by

Comment: Except that this is MySQL *(which doesn't have `ROW_NUMBER()`)*, and that question is Oracle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MySQL, the simplest way is to have a sub-query that finds the last finished time for each handle, then join those results back on to your table to pick out the whole row.

```
SELECT
  execution_records.*
FROM
(
  SELECT
    handle, MAX(finished_at) AS max_finished_at
  FROM
    execution_records
  GROUP BY
    handle
)
  AS summary
INNER JOIN
  execution_records
    ON  execution_records.handle      = summary.handle
    AND execution_records.finished_at = summary.max_finished_at
```

You can still filter this down to specific handles *(rather than all of them)* with a simple `WHERE` clause.

```
WHERE
  summary.handle IN ('task_foo','task_bah')
```

The optimiser will then use macro-like-expansion to push that where clause down in to your aggregate query, as well as the outer query.

Comment: I don't get this solution to work. The query is valid, yet it returns 0 rows for me.

Answer (score 0):

```
select * 
  from exection_records 
  join (select handle, max(finishedAt) max 
          from exection_records 
        group by handle) m 
    on exection_records.finishedAt=max
```

[Demo on sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b782d/1)

Answer (score 0):

```
select id, handle, max(finishedAt) from exection_records group by handle;
```

Here is the output

```
create table exection_records (id INT, handle VARCHAR(20), finishedAt BIGINT);


insert into exection_records values(1, 'a', 10);
insert into exection_records values(2, 'a', 20);
insert into exection_records values(3, 'a', 30);
insert into exection_records values(4, 'b', 15);
insert into exection_records values(5, 'b', 25);
insert into exection_records values(6, 'b', 35);

select id, handle, max(finishedAt) from exection_records group by handle;

id  handle  max(finishedAt)
1   a   30
4   b   35
```

[SqlFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6b8f6/10/0)

Comment: You are selecting `id` but do not include it in the `GROUP BY`.  The MySQL documention then says that the `id` returned is arbitrary.  You could get `1, a, 30` or you could get `2, a, 30` or you could get `3, a, 30`, there are no guarantees.  *(From this page: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/group-by-handling.html `The server is free to choose any value from each group, so unless they are the same, the values chosen are indeterminate.`)*