# How to eliminate a row which having the maximum ID in sql query?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to Eliminate final row which have the maximum ID from a sql query.How can I do it? I tries following query.But it didn't generated records

```sql
SELECT a.DocEntry, a.Project, a.DocTotal, a.U_Installement
FROM OPCH AS a
LEFT JOIN PCH1 AS b
    ON b.DocEntry = a.DocEntry
LEFT JOIN OPOR AS c
    ON c.DocEntry = b.BaseEntry
    AND a.Project = c.Project
WHERE a.CANCELED = 'N'
AND a.Project = c.Project
GROUP BY a.DocEntry, a.Project, a.DocTotal, a.U_Installement
HAVING MAX(a.DocEntry) <> a.DocEntry;
```

Comment: in which table you actually has this id, i mean your table name and column name

Comment: Sample data and desired results would greatly help here.

Comment: Why do you have a `LEFT JOIN` to `OPOR ` when you turn it into an implicit inner join in your `WHERE`? Also [Bad habits to kick : using table aliases like (a, b, c) or (t1, t2, t3)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-table-aliases-like-a-b-c-or-t1-t2-t3).

Comment: The argument is in this post too https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2854257/sql-how-to-select-a-row-having-a-column-with-max-value

Answer (score 2):

Looks like this would work:

```
SELECT a.DocEntry, a.Project, a.DocTotal, a.U_Installement
FROM OPCH AS a
  JOIN PCH1 AS b
    ON b.DocEntry = a.DocEntry
  JOIN OPOR AS c
    ON c.DocEntry = b.BaseEntry
    AND a.Project = c.Project
WHERE a.CANCELED = 'N'
    AND a.DocEntry NOT IN (SELECT MAX(DocEntry) FROM OPCH)
```

Comment: Might as well move `a.Project = c.Project` into the `ON` and change the 2 joins to an `INNER JOIN` too; leaving the `JOIN` to `OPOR` as a `LEFT JOIN` and not changing it to an `INNER JOIN` will change the queries behaviour when you move the clause to the `ON`.

Comment: @Larnu, thank you, that's right, I've fixed my answer

Comment: @Renat . . . This will *not* work, because the maximum entry might be filtered out by other conditions.

Answer (score 2):

it seems to me you want to eliminate each group max id and therefore i used row_number()

```
    with cte as
    (

    SELECT a.DocEntry, a.Project, a.DocTotal, a.U_Installement,
     row_number()over(partitioned by a.Project, a.DocTotal, a.U_Installement
      ordere by a.DocEntry desc) rn
    FROM OPCH AS a
    JOIN PCH1 AS b
        ON b.DocEntry = a.DocEntry
     JOIN OPOR AS c
        ON c.DocEntry = b.BaseEntry
        AND a.Project = c.Project
    WHERE a.CANCELED = 'N'

 ) select * from cte where rn<>1
```

Comment: The join to `PCH1` in an implied `INNER JOIN` too, due to the clause `c.DocEntry = b.BaseEntry` in the `ON` of `OPOR`. There has to be a row from `OPOR` according to the logic in the OP's query, so might as well just make them both an `INNER JOIN`.

Answer (score 0):

First, learn to use *meaningful* table aliases rather than arbitrary letters.  This makes queries much easier to read.

Second, your `WHERE` clause turns the outer joins in to inner joins.

Then, you are removing duplicates -- but these are probably generated by the `JOIN`s.  That can be fixed by using `EXISTS`.

So for your full query:

```
SELECT o.DocEntry, o.Project, o.DocTotal, o.U_Installement
FROM OPCH o
WHERE o.CANCELED = 'N' AND
      EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM PCH1 p JOIN
                   OPOR op
                   ON op.DocEntry = p.BaseEntry
              WHERE p.DocEntry = o.DocEntry AND
                    op.Project = o.Project
             );
```

Then, you can incorporate window functions into this:

```
SELECT DocEntry, Project, DocTotal, U_Installement
FROM (SELECT o.DocEntry, o.Project, o.DocTotal, o.U_Installement,
             MAX(o.DocEntry) OVER () as max_DocEntry
      FROM OPCH o
      WHERE o.CANCELED = 'N' AND
            EXISTS (SELECT 1
                    FROM PCH1 p JOIN
                         OPOR op
                         ON op.DocEntry = p.BaseEntry
                    WHERE p.DocEntry = o.DocEntry AND
                          op.Project = o.Project
                   )
     ) o
WHERE docEntry < max_docEntry;
```

Answer (score 0):

We use this method regually:

```
select a.* from ( 
    SELECT a.DocEntry, a.Project, a.DocTotal, a.U_Installement
    FROM OPCH a 
    GROUP BY a.DocEntry, a.Project, a.DocTotal, a.U_Installement
    HAVING MAX(a.DocEntry) <> a.DocEntry 
) AS a 
LEFT JOIN PCH1 AS b
    ON b.DocEntry = a.DocEntry
LEFT JOIN OPOR AS c
    ON c.DocEntry = b.BaseEntry
    AND a.Project = c.Project
WHERE a.CANCELED = 'N'
```